# Using a dictionary with user input

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-3.4

I am fairly new to programming and I've been experimenting with dictionaries in Python. However, I just updated to Python 3.4 and code that was previously usable is not functioning properly after the update. I thought I had cleared most everything up, but now my dictionary seems to be broken.

The code runs fine until I try to call on the dictionary. Here is an example of code that previously worked correctly in Python 2.7:

```
userPrompt = input("Month: ")

months = {
        1: jan,
        2: feb,
        3: mar,
    }

months[userPrompt]()
```

It seems to have an issue with that final line. Do I need to write the dictionary differently, or address it differently?

Comment: The user input **is always a string** (for changes between 2.x and 3.x, see https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#builtins). Either convert your keys to strings, or the input to integers. See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/20449427/3001761

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
int(userPrompt)
```

to get the integer value of your input string. In python 3, the `input` function doesn't use the `eval` function. Instead, it returns the raw string, like python's 2 `raw_input` function. It's up to the programmer to convert it to an integer.

For example in python2:

```
>>> type(input())
42
<class 'int'>
```

In python3:

```
>>> type(input())
42
<class 'str'>
```